# Issue with TagBuilder.MergeAttribute for parameter null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to use Razor's feature not to produce attribute output inside a tag in case when attribute's value is null. So when Razor meets <div class="@var"> where @var is null, the output will be mere <div>. I've created some Html extension method to write text inside  tag. The method takes header text, level (h1..h6), and html attributes as simple object. The code is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString WriteHeader(this HtmlHelper html, string s, int? hLevel = 1, object htmlAttributes = null)
{
    if ((hLevel == null) || 
        (hLevel < 1 || hLevel > 4) ||
        (s.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()))
        return new MvcHtmlString("");

    string cssClass = null, cssId = null, cssStyle = null;

    if (htmlAttributes != null)
    {
        var T = htmlAttributes.GetType();

        var propInfo = T.GetProperty("class");
        var o = propInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes);
        cssClass = o.ToString().IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? null : o.ToString();

        propInfo = T.GetProperty("id");
        o = propInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes);
        cssId = o.ToString().IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? null : o.ToString();

        propInfo = T.GetProperty("style");
        o = propInfo.GetValue(htmlAttributes);
        cssStyle = o.ToString().IsNullOrWhiteSpace() ? null : o.ToString();
    }

    var hTag = new TagBuilder("h" + hLevel);

    hTag.MergeAttribute("id", cssId);
    hTag.MergeAttribute("class", cssClass);
    hTag.MergeAttribute("style", cssStyle);
    hTag.InnerHtml = s;

    return new MvcHtmlString(hTag.ToString());
}
```

I found that in spite of null values for "class" and "style" attributes TagBuilder still puts them as empty strings, like <h1 class="" style=""> But for id attribute it surprisingly works, so when id's value is null, there is no id attribute in tag.

My question - is such behavior something that should actually happen? How can I achieve absent attributes with null values using TagBuilder?

I tried this in VS2013, MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

**TagBuilder** writes all specified attributes, except an empty or null "id" attribute. The following is the code that uses the class **TagBuilder** internally:

```
    private void AppendAttributes(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        foreach (var attribute in Attributes)
        {
            string key = attribute.Key;
            if (String.Equals(key, "id", StringComparison.Ordinal /* case-sensitive */) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Value))
            {
                continue; // DevDiv Bugs #227595: don't output empty IDs
            }
            string value = HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(attribute.Value);
            sb.Append(' ')
                .Append(key)
                .Append("=\"")
                .Append(value)
                .Append('"');
        }
    }
```

You can create the Html extension like this:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString WriteHeader(this HtmlHelper html, string s, int? hLevel = 1, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
        var hTag = new TagBuilder("h" + hLevel);
        hTag.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        hTag.InnerHtml = s;
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(hTag.ToString());
    }
```

and, for example, can be used as follows:

```
@Html.WriteHeader("hello1", 1)
@Html.WriteHeader("hello2", 2, new { @class = string.Empty, style = string.Empty })
@Html.WriteHeader("hello3", 3, new { id = "id3", @class = "css3", style = "style3" })
```

generating the following HTML code:

```
<h1>hello1</h1>
<h2 class="" style="">hello2</h2>
<h3 class="css3" id="id3" style="style3">hello3</h3>
```